# Access string resource by key

Tags: android

I am trying to use an xml resource file to store the mappings of certain values. Then, in my app, when i want to get their values, i would like a way to just access the values in the xml file by key. The problem is that I dont know the key beforehand. There is some logic that evaluates what key to get and then i have to get that key's value. For example:

```
    switch(id) {
       case 0:
         key = hello;
         break;
       case 1:
         key = world;
         break;
    }
```

Now i would like to access the value for these keys that i have stored in an xml file. How can i accomplish this? I dont want to use the SharedPreferences and i cant exactly use resources.getString(R.string. *_* ) because i dont know the key beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the R.id. within the switch, for example:

```
public String getStringById(id) {
    switch(id) {
       case 0:
         return getString(R.id.hello); break;
       case 1:
         return getString(R.id.world); break;
    }
}
```

But if you can't do it like that you could get the `int` id for the String like so:

```
int text_id = YourActivity.this.getResources()
    .getIdentifier("hello", "string", YourActivity.this.getPackageName());
```

So your code will now be like this:

```
String key = "";
switch(id) {
   case 0:
     key = hello;
     break;
   case 1:
     key = world;
     break;
}
int text_id = YourActivity.this.getResources()
    .getIdentifier(key, "string", YourActivity.this.getPackageName());
String text = YourActivity.this.getResources()
    .getString(text_id);
return text;
```

Comment: the switch was a simple example. My real use case is that i have a dic t with keys and i would like the value to come from a resource file. So i check if(userInput == dict.containsKey(userInput)) -> get the resource xml entry

Comment: @JohnBaum Look at the second example

Answer (score 2):

if i understood correctly, you only have a String "key" to get the resources?

```
getResources().getString(
        getResources().getIdentifier(key, "string", getPackageName()))
```